# How do I send a bytearray to server and detect progress?

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload, http-post, progress-indicator

I am using Flash runtime (flash player 10). I have a flv encoded bytearray which I need to send to the server( simple php, no FMS or socket servers) and save there. I can use the urlLoader and post everything but then i won't get the progress percentage, so instead I tried saving it with a file reference like this:

```
var url_ref:URLRequest = new URLRequest("save_vid.php");    
url_ref.contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary="+getBoundary();
url_ref.data = _baFlvEncoder.byteArray;
url_ref.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var upfileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
upfileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onUploadProgress);
upfileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoUploadComplete);
upfileRef.upload(url_ref);
```

But when I try this, I am getting an error:

```
Error #2037: Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful.
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: Removed PHP tag as this is a pure actionscript problem and the receiving server is irrelevant. "Functions called in incorrect sequence, **or earlier call was unsuccessful**." - sounds like you need some error checking on a method call somewhere.

Comment: the problem is the filereference expects the user to actually browse and select a file before it can function, or else it will throw that error. Problem is, i am not uploading a file stored in the user's system, rather I am uploading a dynamically generated bytearray.

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/02/28/error-error-2037-functions-called-in-incorrect-sequence-or-earlier-call-was-unsuccessful/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var vars :URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.bytearray  = _baFlvEncoder.byteArray;

var req :URLRequest = new URLRequest("save_vid.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = vars;

var ldr :URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded );
ldr.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError );
ldr.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress );
ldr.load( req );

function onProgress( e:ProgressEvent ):void 
{           
    trace( "Progress: " + e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal );
}
```

and in PHP

```
$bytearray = $_POST['bytearray']
```

Comment: does the complete event fire?

Comment: yes, the complete event fires. Also the IOError fires if I post something way too large....but nothing related to progress fires